# Is it safe to use inherit in css font-family

Tags: html, css

I want to use a special font for some HTML element text. But I want to set parent font style when failed rendering special font on browser.

**Example CSS code:**

```
.SmoothText {
    font-family: "Special Font name", inherit;
}
```

Is it safe or not to mix font name and `inherit`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inherit` can only exist by itself as a value for any property. What you have is invalid.

If you want to add a font family to a parent font stack, you will need to specify the parent font stack again.

Answer (score 1):

`inherit` is a property value which means that property takes its value from its parent.

IF you want to add font family to the parent ,font stack has your solution.
See this [Link](http://cssfontstack.com/)